# How simulate a navigationController/UITableView DrillDown in a smaller area of the iPad?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have a 2-deep menu (UITableView) that is a subview in the main one on the iPad. So, this is not a controller, is a regular UITableView.

However, I want to provide the same visual feedback as with navigation controller, so when a item in the first-level of the table is selected, get push the second and the ability to go back.

This is not in a splitview, and for this UI, a splitview is not the answer.  Think as if the table is a box inside a bigger one, with other boxs around.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by creating a master view controller that held a navigation controller and any of the sub-layer views. I followed the same general principle as found in Apple's [DrillDownSave](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DrillDownSave/Introduction/Intro.html) sample except I skipped the Window object and the AppDelegate object in the xib file. I used a UIView instead since I was using a UIViewController to manage everything.

All I had to do after that was create an instance of the master view controller in whatever view I wanted to place it in and set its frame to wherever I wanted it to show up in that view. One interesting issue I ran into was that the navigation controller wanted to span the width of the screen even if its parent view was set smaller. All I had to do was set its width in its frame at the same time I set its master view's frame and everything worked out well.

It's a lot of code to put here but the basic layout goes:

- Some View Controller

  - Master View Controller for the navigation item (set as a property of the "some" view controller and instantiated/positioned/added as a subview in its viewDidLoad)

    - UINavigationController (in the xib, like the Apple example)

      - First level view controller with UITable
    - Second level view controller with UITable
    - Third level view controller with UITable
  - Placeholder view in the xib to line up navigation item master a little easier

*note - I did not use a leaf view like the Apple example because I didn't need it for my purposes

I don't know if I explained it very well so if you need further clarification let me know. Hope this helps!